# Find out how many pages of results there are from within a paginated CakePHP Controller

Tags: cakephp, pagination

I'm using CakePHP's `paginate` method within a controller. I wish to find out how many pages of results were generated. This is easy enough within the *view* (`$paginator->counter()`) but I'd like to access this information from within the *controller* itself. Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$this->params['paging'][<MODEL NAME>]['pageCount']
```

try using this. I think it's what you need

Answer (score 4):

A little bit of searching bought this up

```
$this->params['paging'][$model]['count']
```

Where `$model` is your model name.

http://whilefalse.net/2010/11/09/cakephp-get-paginator-count-controller/

Comment: Great! Would love to know what you searched for, though? I couldn't find that anywhere :(

Comment: Searched for http://www.google.lk/search?q=getting%20paginate%20count%20in%20controller%20cakephp. 4th result on the page :)

Comment: Ah, it was the magic word 'count' that made the difference. I was trying things like 'pages' or 'number of results'

Answer (score 2):

In CakePHP 3 you can access the parameters the following way after you have called the method paginate().

```
$this->request->params['paging']['Model']['count']
```